# Delegate doesn't seem to fire from RBQFetchedResultController

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, realm

I'm currently struggling to get the delegates to fire using RBQFetchedResultController (https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController). This controller is a drop-in replacement for NSFetchedResultController when using Realm database. I was wondering if anyone has had troubles with setting up the delegate? The FRC does perform a fetch, but it doesn't notify the delegate when new information needs to be shown.

EDIT:

```
 - (RBQFetchedResultsController *)FRC {
     if (_FRC != nil)
     {
         return _FRC;
     }
     else
     {
         _FRC = [[RealmController sharedInstance] createFormTemplateFRC];
         _FRC.delegate = self;
         return _FRC;
     } }
```

This code shows how I created and set the delegate for the FRC.

Comment: Show your code, esp. setting the delegate and the delegate method. How did you check for (non-)receiving messages.

Comment: Please add the code to your Q.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - Done. Please see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I checked for the non-receiving of delegate messages by setting breakpoints in the functions the FRC is supposed to call when new information needs to be presented, but none of the breakpoints trigger. I know the delegate is set to the correct VC when I look in the lldb and print the FRC object, the delegate is set.

Comment: 1. `-createFormTemplateFRC` does not exist. Likely it should be `-createFromTemplateFRC`. 2. `+sharedInstance` returns an instance object. What is `-createFromTemplateFRC` is supposed to do? 3. Did you check for its return value being `nil`?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad createFormTemplateFRC is a function I created that creates the FRC for me. I know it works because after the data is inserted into Realm, if I pop the view and go back into it, it is able to display the data.

Comment: You create an instance object by sending an unparametrized message to an unparametrized shared instance object? Is it clear to you that you have two different instances? (BTW: It is no function, but a method.)

Comment: I've tried moving the code in createFormTemplateFRC into the VC class itself to simplify the code, but still no dice.

Comment: I think that there is a problem with fundamental understanding, not with code location.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Thanks for your help, but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to use the RBQNotificationManager class methods to register changes.

Reference: https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController/issues/63